# Why is it that the url I use changes whenever I run the code but when I paste it manually it works fine?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, stock, python-requests-html

I am trying to get quarterly revenue data for the 3 stocks using python. When I run my code it takes this starting url `https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/tsla/financials/?p=quarterly` and ends up searching this url:`https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/tsla/financials/`. This gets left out `?p=quarterly`. But when I copy and paste it manually it works fine. I have no idea what is going wrong and I have tried everything in my knowledge to work this problem. No matter what I always get the annual data instead of the quarterly.  Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you!

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

tickers = ["AMZN", "FB", "TSLA"]

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'
}

for ticker in tickers:
    # construct the URL directly as a string
    url = f"https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/{ticker}/financials/?p=quarterly"
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table')

    # Convert the table to a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

    # Get the first three date columns
    columns = df.columns[1:4]

    # Find the row that contains 'Revenue'
    row = df[df.iloc[:,0].str.contains('Revenue')]

    # Get the values for the last 3 quarters
    values = row[columns].values[0]

    print(f"For {ticker}:")
    print(f"Revenue for last quarter ({columns[0]}) is: {values[0]}")
    print(f"Revenue for 2 quarters ago ({columns[1]}) is: {values[1]}")
    print(f"Revenue for 3 quarters ago ({columns[2]}) is: {values[2]}\n")
```

I tried using user agents to go around any bot blockers, I even tried saving all the urls to a text file and calling them for specific stocks I want. Nothing works. I always get the annual data instead of the quarterly.

Comment: I think I found the issue, for AMZN and FB the real url https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/AMZN/financials/?p=quarterly redirects to https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/AMZN/financials, only for tsla it is sticking to https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/AMZN/financials/?p=quarterly

Answer (score 1):

These code snippets should work fine and get the quarterly values as per the requirements, ***Two changes required-***

**1. Rename FB to META**

**2. Lowercase each ticker, see the comments**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

tickers = ["AMZN", "META", "TSLA"] # changes: Rename FB to META

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'
}

for ticker in tickers:
    ticker = ticker.lower() # Changes: Make ticker to lowercase
    # construct the URL directly as a string
    url = f"https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/{ticker}/financials/?p=quarterly"
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table')

    # Convert the table to a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

    # Get the first three date columns
    columns = df.columns[1:4]

    # Find the row that contains 'Revenue'
    row = df[df.iloc[:,0].str.contains('Revenue')]

    # Get the values for the last 3 quarters
    values = row[columns].values[0]

    print(f"For {ticker}:")
    print(f"Revenue for last quarter ({columns[0]}) is: {values[0]}")
    print(f"Revenue for 2 quarters ago ({columns[1]}) is: {values[1]}")
    print(f"Revenue for 3 quarters ago ({columns[2]}) is: {values[2]}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
url = f"https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/{ticker.lower()}/financials/?p=quarterly"
```

If you pay attention, when manually navigating to the link https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/AMZN/financials/?p=quarterly, you get redirected to https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/amzn/financials (developer workaround or who knows what else), so you need to use lowercase in the URL request to avoid losing the "q" parameter.

And you don't need to manually specify a header for whatever you may be using it for.

Comment: [edit] your answer to add an explanation, don't add an explanation in the comments.